# ScrollView doesn't display whole content of ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I have the following xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.movie_detail.MovieDetailActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn_back"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/movie_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/movie_image" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_country"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_description" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_runtime"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_country" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_released"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_runtime" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_tagline"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_released" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_year"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="aaaaaaaa"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_tagline" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </ScrollView>


    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_no_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_information"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I added such a big marginTop to all views just to test how scrollview works. And when I open the activity I see this:

[image]

So, as you see, there's no `year` textview in this screen. I specially added default text to display that this problem exists. I watched on the previous questions related to this problem and usually the solution was to add paddings or margins to scrollview. As you can see, I did it and it didn't help. So, what's the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: Is it not just below the tagline, if you scroll down a bit?

Comment: @Speed, unfortunately no. I scrolled to the bottom on this screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottom margin you have assigned to `tv_year` will not work until you assign related constraint with it.

So add below attribute in `tv_year` textview to apply bottom margin too.

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

so your final `tv_year` view looks like,

```
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_year"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="aaaaaaaa"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_tagline" />
```

**Update:**
You have also forget one attribute on `SwipeRefreshLayout`.
Add below attribute with it.

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

**FYI:** Also add `android:clipToPadding="false"` attribute with ScrollView. It'll looks better.

Comment: Unfortunately it also didn't help. It is still not visible